# Como inserir o bloco do Slider Revolution Magento Extension em arquivos phtml?

Tags: php, magento, temas

Estou fazendo algumas tentativas improdutivas de inserir o bloco criado pela extensão para Magento dentro dos arquivos `phtml` do tema e já tentei inserir como bloco do próprio `Slider Revolution` e também coloquei o `shortcode` do plugin dentro de um bloco nativo do Magento para tentar chamar o html através da inserção do bloco no arquivo do tema. Tenho erros do tipo **a variável** `$this` **está chamando um objeto que não existe.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei editar os arquivos `xml` do tema, então nem tentei fazer isso. O código que estou tentando inserir dentro do `phtml` é este:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('nwdrevslider/revslider')->setAlias('fashion_slider')->toHtml();
```

**Erro**

> Fatal error: Using **$this** when not in object context in ...

Alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar uma solução ou seguir um raciocínio para fazer funcionar?

Comment: Marcos, Você já tentou inserir esse Shortcode dentro de uma página CMS, para ver se ela está funcionando, antes de mais nada? Quando você inseriu dentro do Bloco nativo, qual erro gerou? Abs